# Use Geofirex with React Native and rnfirebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, geo, geofirestore

I'm Creating a React native App and I am using React Native Firebase (rnfirebase).
I making an app that uses firestore to store a list of items that are near a user.
I want to use geoqueries in firestore to retrieve nearby items.

Do I have to install firebase again using the web SDK from the official firebase, or can I just use the rnfirebase and firestore that I have already set up?

Thanks for any help.

> I have Decided to use Geofirestore instead, as it has more downloads then GeoFirex and the api looks to be good.
>
> **Update:**
>
> Just to clarify I'm using React Native0.57.2, Geofirestore2.2.2 and it works with rnfirebase5.0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to make sure when you upload the locations in firestore that you import using 'import { GeoFirestore } from "geofirestore"'. Geofirestore saves the data in firestore as a pair longitude and latitude. You can also upload other data that relates to the item such as 'name', 'model', 'year', etc. You don't need to install firebase again. You can use the firestore and just install the geofirestore node module.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Thank you for your answer, but I'm looking to use GeoFirex, not GeoFirestore. Since asking my question I have managed to be able to very basically write to firestore using rnfirebase. I am now trying to get the read working, and be able to show items within a certain radius while using the rnfirebase implementation. Thank you though. Im not sure which is better geofirex or geofirestore, but Im going to give geofirex a try

Comment: ok glad to hear it worked out. Sorry about that I know GeoFirestore works really well. I've gone to firebase meetups and they discussed this node module. Hope it all works out for you.

Comment: Ok well thanks for that, yeah that makes GeoFirestore sound very good! Ill have another look at, but I think Ill just try getting GeoFirex working first, Ill be happiest picking the one that will be mostly likely to be supported in the future. where they official firebase meetups ?

Comment: yes it was centered around firebase. Not sure where your located, this was in new york. download the 'meetup' app. you'll find some in your area hopefully.

Comment: Hi @Kieran, after looking into Geofirestore more, I have decided to go with GeoFirestore as it looks to have more users and is more supported, and after reading through the api it doesn't look too bad, so thank you for your answer! and I'm from Westport on the west coast of Ireland

Comment: @Kieran if you by chance recall which meetup specifically it was, I would love to know. And Andrew I'm happy to hear geofirestore worked for you!

Comment: @MichaelSolati its work brilliant so far! thank you for making it ! :) and just to let you know I'm using it with rnfirebase, as I think I mentioned to you before somewhere. thank you very much! :)

Comment: @MichaelSolati sorry I'm now seeing this post. It was at a meetup in the city for firebase. you presented earlier this year. It was a three day hackathon if I my memory serves me well.